# Text isn't wrapping inside absolute positioned container

Tags: css-position, word-wrap, css

I've created tooltips that are absolutely positioned and have divs inside of them that have `max-width: 200px;`. The text within the divs are not wrapping to the next line, however. They're going outside of the container even though there are spaces in the text, so it's not a word-break issue. See image below:

**Edit:** The tooltips are pulling in the text from their trigger element's `title` attribute and that seems to be the problem. If the content is hard-coded, the text wraps just fine.

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="tooltip">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis malesuada, lectus eget gravida eleifend, odio libero hendrerit elit.</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.tooltip{
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #303030;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

.tooltip  div{
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red; /* See where element is */
}
```

This seems so obvious, but I cannot think of what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to wrap fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EqyWz/

Comment: Show us a complete code, looks like your issue is not related to that part of code you've shown.

Comment: Ah, found what it is. The tooltips are getting their content from their trigger element's title attribute. If I simply hard-code in the content, it wraps just fine. I'm not sure why that would make a difference, though...

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with the way you're injecting the text into the `.tooltip` element. Try something like this (using jQuery):

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
  $('.tooltip div').html($('.trigger').attr('title'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DyxkA/